# MVC Base Controller implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We are now in the process of rebuilding some legacy WebForm apps using MVC 5. For one in particular the entire site is dynamic and built from returning a lot of markup from a back-end database, and that markup is different based on the domain name returned...

I got to the first stage of this one (the others not so difficult), building a dynamic menu and started scratching my head (and a few other body parts). In WebForms it was easy, MasterPage and code-behind, done and dusted...

After spending most of the day Googling I gather creating a Base Controller is the way to go... But there seems to be very little material showing how this can be achieved... What is out there is followed by a plethora of comments about how the author has got it all wrong and is direct violation of the MVC pattern...

Therefore, the question is, can someone provide a link to some documentation about how I can add a dynamic menu to a _Layout?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you thing using a `BaseController` is appropriate for this. If you want a 'menu' on each page, use `@{ Html.RenderAction("actionName", "controllerName"); }` in the layout and have the action return a partial view of the menu

Comment: You can add dynamic menu set in a partial view using `Html.RenderAction` or `Html.RenderPartial` in layout page and set an action method to render it. However your question seems likely asking about off-site resource, which may classified as off-topic (edit to explain your problem in detail before someone takes vote to close).

Comment: Hi Stephen - I just followed the BaseController breadcrumbs. So, if I am reading you correctly, I create a partial view with a menu that I can populate from the Controller, then add that to the _Layout? Seems like a better idea :-) Will try that approach in the morning - thank you

Comment: Tetsuya - you and Stephen have the right idea I think - not sure what you mean about 'off-site resource' or why the question would be off topic, seems a straightforward MVC question to me. I got more information in a few minutes than the rest of the day researching it!

Comment: @gchq, Asking for an off-site resource (_can someone provide a link to some documentation ..._) is off-topic (and the question will eventually be closed)

Comment: Stephen - seems to be getting very political here these days :-( I think your comment is the answer if you want to post it as such. Thanks